# How to count the row/loop while reading csv

Tags: node.js

Hey so we're parsing/reading a csv with reviews and then performing an api call for each row, however the api has rate limiting (300 calls each 5 minutes).

How to make something in below code so I know what row I'm at, and then be able to use that value to select the row to continue later on? Like current row = 299, stop script, and then be able to continue/restart from the next row (300). Something like a batch function.

See below the code.

```
async function createReview2() {
// reading csv
    const csv = require('csvtojson');
    const jsonArray = await csv({
        delimiter: ';',
        noheader: false,
    }).fromFile(__dirname + "/csv/review.csv");
    
// performing loop
    for (let d of jsonArray) {

// filling json payload body        
        let rev = {
            "review": {
                "createdAt": moment(d.date_added, "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").format() ,
                "isVisible": true,
                "score": d.rating,
                "name": d.author,
                "content": d.text,
                "language": "en",
                "customer": "122862444",
                "product": d['xx ID']    
            }
        };
        await axios({
            method: 'post',
            data:rev,
            url: 'https://xx:xx@api.xx.com/en/reviews.json',
        });*/

// waiting a bit after the api call        
        sleep(5000);
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just define some counter `i` before the loop and increment it in each iteration

```
let count = 0;
const duration = 60000;
for (let d of jsonArray) {
  ....

  if (++count > 300) {
    await async_wait(duration);
    count = 0;
  }
}
```

where `async_wait` is something like

```
async function async_wait(duration) {
   return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, duration));
}
```